# Pages getting (deleted) when using shmget and shmat

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-memory

I wrote the following 2 test programs, one that uses `shmat` and another that uses `shmget` and execve's the first binary.

The code is as follows :-

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *retval;
  long shmid = atol(argv[1]);

  retval = shmat(shmid, NULL, SHM_RDONLY);
  printf("%p\n", retval);
}
```

And the wrapper file,

```
int setupshm(char *name) {
  int shmid;
  shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 100, IPC_CREAT|0666);
  return shmid;
}

int main() {

  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
  char **envp = NULL;
  char *argv[3];
  char num[10];

  sprintf(num, "%d", setupshm("whatever"));

  argv[1] = "./test";
  argv[2] = num;
  argv[3] = NULL;

  execve("./test", argv, envp);
}

else { int status; wait(pid, &status, 0); }
}
```

I run the wrapper program in gdb, intercept the execve, debug the test program, see that shmget succeeds; then inspect its /proc/pid/maps and I see that the page corresponding to the shmget shows up as "(Deleted)". Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move the `setupshm()` before the fork-call. In the current version. you're creating the shm in the child, then you're overwriting the child with a new process. That's why the memory is marked for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong; nothing is being deleted. The `(Deleted)` notation is just how Linux represents mappings of files that have no named link in the filesystem.

Comment: You can get some additional information about SysV IPC objects from the `ipcs` command, including the true state of the "marked for deletion" flag (which shows as `dest` in the `status` column). Also you might become interested in the `ipcrm` command when you realize how many unused shm segments you've left lying around